# running ddl file through sh

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, unix

I am having issue when running a ddl script file through sh on one of the servers but executes fine on another. The script is as below

```
sqlplus mgr/$1@$2 @export_all_tables_mgr.ddl
if [ $? != 0 ];
then
echo 'ERROR exporting MGR data, Refer to .CSV and .CTL files for detail.'   | tee -a MGR_ExtractionLog.log
fi
```

It uses sqlplus to run the ddl file but one the rogue server, it would just connect to sql plus and won't do anything.

```
oracle@dbsdev55z2 $ export_all_tables_mgr.sh password servicename

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Thu Jan 24 08:39:18 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

To mention here, I am using Oracle 10g here. export_all_tables_mgr.ddl file is as below

```
      alter session set nls_date_format = 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS';

      @drop_table_temp_extraction_counts.ddl

      @create_table_temp_extraction_counts.ddl

      WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT -1
      WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT -1

      SET HEADING OFF
      SET FEEDBACK OFF
      SET VERIFY OFF

      SPOOL MGR_ExtractionLog.log
      SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), '- Start extract process' FROM dual;
      SPOOL OFF

      define TableName=TABLE1
      @ExportTable

      define TableName=TABLE2
      @ExportTable

      SPOOL MGR_ExtractionLog.log append
      SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), '- End extract process' FROM dual;
      SPOOL OFF

      EXIT 0
```

Comment: Seeing the `.ddl` file might help, at least how it starts. Is `sqlplus` an alias or a wrapper function on the server that sits at the prompt, e.g. so it automatically connects as a specific user? Can you check if you're actually connected as `mgr`? (Just a simple `select user from dual` would do).

Comment: I have updated the question with .ddl file and Yes I am connected as mgr

Comment: If you do just `sqlplus` from the command line, does it prompt for credentials, or are you logged in automatically? That's the only reason I can think of off-hand that the file wold be ignored. You can also run it as `sqlplus mgr/$1@$2 < export_all_tables_mgr.ddl` which ought to work even if it was aliased.

Comment: @AlexPoole it asks for credential if I just type `sqlplus`. I have also given all permissions to the files.

Comment: does it spool the log file?

Comment: @ninesided , no it does not when you run through the sh file.

Comment: if you run `sqlplus mgr/password@servicename @export_all_tables_mgr.ddl` from the command line on its own, not through the shell script, does it work?

Comment: @ninesided : yes it works the way you said, it only doesn't work when using via .sh file

Comment: what shell environment are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is a shell problem, try adding the following as the first line of your shell script to tell it which interpreter to use:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Comment: I was running the script as `sh script.sh password username`. Would it make different adding the shell bang at the top of the file in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure - you would have to test it

Comment: @Junaid - it may be that you're running in another shell for your login session, and switching to `sh` when you run the script; in which case an environment script (e.g. `.profile`) could be causing the problem. (It still sounds to me like something in there is defining `sqlplus` as a function). If you run it as `$SHELL script.sh password username` it might not have the same problem?